# Detect If Offline - in C# WebBrowser component?

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control, offline

We're working on a wrapped WebBrowser component.  We'd like to display one page (e.g. oursite.com/thispage.html) if the user is online and another page (e.g. C:\somewhere\thispage_offline.html) if the user is offline.  I'm able to to properly display both pages, but my issue is detecting the online/offline status.

I tried 
[WebBrowser.IsOffline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.isoffline%28VS.80%29.aspx); however it seems that only relays the Offline Mode status, not whether or not the computer is actually able to reach the internet.

Is there a way to detect this from the WebBrowser component?  Is there a way at all?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to check for internet connectivity is to ping your server.

Try this code:

```
public static bool IsOnline() {
    var pinger = new Ping();

    try {
        return pinger.Send("oursite.com").Status == IPStatus.Success;
    } catch(SocketException) { return false; } catch(PingException) { return false; }
}
```

Alternatively, you can try using the [`WebRequest` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) to send a request to a simple page on your site and see whether it succeeds.  This is a better option because it will also make sure that IIS (or Apache) is running on the server.

Comment: Ping didn't work for our server (though it worked for my personal site...weird), but WebRequest did.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What if you just used the [Ping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) class to see if the site is available?